# Do I have to compute the second moment along principal axes to calculate the maximum deflection of a cantilever beam with irregular cross-section?

Tags: home-experiment, structural-beam

Do I have to compute the area moment of inertia along the [principal axis of the cross-section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem), in order to find the maximum beam deflection of a cantilever beam with a random polygonal cross-section?

As far as I know, to compute the maximum beam deflection of a cantilever beam with a polygonal cross-section under a point load at the tip of the beam, I can use the following equations:

**1)** Compute [Second Moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area):

[image: Random Polygonal Cross-section]

[image]

**2)** Compute [maximum deflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Bernoulli_beam_theory):

[image: Clamped cantilever beam with point load]

[image: Maximum Deflection Formula]

Now, the second moment is computed in two directions that are no necessarily the principal axes of the shape.

Assuming P = <1000N, 0,0> i.e. a 1000N point load in the y-direction only, then the calculation would give me the deflection in that direction, assuming I use the the moment of inertia calculated in that direction.

If I were to solve for the principal axes of the shape, then I would have to transform the force vector P into the coordinate frame of the new basis, and then compute the maximum deflection based on the principal axes.

I would like to understand if and why, I need to solve for principal components first to compute the maximum deflection correctly? Given that the force vector is in the direction of one of the axis of the coordinate system used to compute the area moment of inertia (2nd moment).